# Can we please roll back the Workplace theme update?

Tags: feature-request, design, css

Re: [The Workplace updated site theme is ready for testing!](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5706/437)

I'm unclear about what problems the updated theme was supposed to solve, but I can definitely tell you about two problems it introudced:

1. Wasted space with the introduction of a left margin toolbar that nobody asked for.
2. When we're voting to close a question that we suspect is a duplicate, "Related Questions" is no longer displayed on the right margin. So we have to do additional work to find that duplicate.

---

So...

Can we please roll back the Workplace theme update?

Comment: Nope. You're stuck it. In the words of my dear sweet granny, you can like it or you can lump it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal place to report these issues would be to contribute them as a pair of answers (one per issue) in

[The Workplace updated site theme is ready for testing!](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/the-workplace-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)

Answering there should ping the Jon Ericson (the guy who rolled out the changes).  If you take a look at the liked question, you'll see where others have reported issues and gotten a response back.

Jon's a great guy, but he might not be scanning threads in all Meta sites looking for issues to address - he's more likely to follow his notifications for his questions.

You've linked to this question in your question here, but don't seem to have contributed your own issues there.  I'd really advise that you do that.

Answer (score 2):

The design changes were made across the network to enable the team to maintain design elements on 174 different sites.  Before this, each (non-beta) site had its own custom CSS and making a change to the UI often broke *something, somewhere* because of that.  That's a done deal; SE isn't going to roll that back.  With the new design framework, sites can individually customize some things (like colors, the header graphic, fonts, and some other things), but the underlying structure, including the left column and the responsive design, remains the same for everybody.

I agree that the left column is annoyingly wasteful.  Fortunately [you can turn that off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311237/162102).  That still doesn't help with the *right* column being too greedy on smaller displays, but it still helps a lot.

See the posts linked in the post that you linked to for more information on this design update.

Comment: OP Asked to roll back theme. The answer is, it won't happen...  Both question and answer got two downvotes. What is the meaning of it?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson beats me.  You'd think that people who dislike one would like the other and vice-versa.  Eh, people are hard to understand sometimes.  *Shrug*